# Download and save a file with proof that it was downloaded from a specific server/url on a specific date?

Tags: http, curl, wget, hash, timestamp

Assuming the file was downloaded over http is this possible? I'm guessing there could be some way to do it using a hash and a timestamp however I'm not sure how you could prove nothing was tampered with including the downloaded file itself.

EDIT: As vonbrand suggested if the origin site provided a signed cert it would be a start. However, if the site doesn't provide any certs is there a clever way to loop in some third party?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have on your machine, you can fake all day long. The file would have to come with some sort of independent proof, probably a signed certificate given by the origin website.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the origin site doesn't provide any certs. I'm wondering if there is some clever way to loop in a third party.

Answer (score 0):

Do you of any tech savvy lawyers that can provide a suitable certificate?

Public notaries make excellent third parties.